# Android PopupMenu to display a webpage on webview

Tags: android, webview, popupmenu

I am learning to develop an Android App and I'm kinda new to Android Programming so pardon me if this question is.. well, dumb.

My android app is just simple, it only displays a website using webview.

I was able to have a button to display a webpage in the webview form using this code.

```
Button contact = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttoncontact);
contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "http://example.com/index.php";
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);              
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do now is to have a popup menu to display a certain webpage as well..
However, I am stuck on this part.. and I don't actually know what to do now. I have read and search for every documents and tutorials available on developer.android.com..

here's where the part I am stuck at..

MainActivity.java

```
public void showPopup(View v) {

   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
   MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());  
   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        //I don't know what to write from here.
            //Say for example I have three popup menu items that shows
            //different webpages.

        return true;
    }
});
   popup.show();
}
```

activity_main.xml which contains the Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonmenu"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showPopup"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonxml_menu" />
```

actions.xml which contains my popup menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item  android:title="@string/next_change"/>
<item  android:title="@string/coming_soon"/>
<item  android:title="@string/ticket_pricing"/>
```

I wanted, say for example, the next_change popup menu to display a certain webpage, same with the latter items.. any help will be appreciated.